# Mattermost and Azure AD integration

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, mattermost

I am trying to configure Azure AD as a part of single sign in Mattermost. However, I'm not able to find any relevant documentation.

Any leads could help.

I have already gone through the following documentations -

1. https://docs.mattermost.com/onboard/sso-office.html
2. https://docs.mattermost.com/onboard/ad-ldap.html

I'm not sure if these documentations are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mattermost integrates with Azure AD using [Open ID Connect authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oidc) to enable SSO between Azure AD, Mattermost and other Azure AD enabled apps using Azure AD credentials.

Basically, you need to [setup or own an Azure AD Tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant) (Dismiss the [Social and local accounts section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant#social-and-local-accounts)), create an app registration and configure OpenID Connect authentication as detailed in the [Mattermost documentation](https://docs.mattermost.com/onboard/sso-office.html).

https://docs.mattermost.com/onboard/ad-ldap.html is intended for on-premise Active Directory using LDAP which is not supported in Azure AD.